Как вывести название файла через ссылку с Яндекс диска?
Пишу телеграмм-бота на aiogram.
Задача: по ссылке на яндекс-диск, которую отправил пользователь, вывести в консоль Python название файла, не скачивая его. Например, когда ссылка вставляется в ТГ, то в сообщении сразу подсвечивается имя файла. Как он это парсит?

При отправленном сообщении:

Пробовала через bs4, но капча не даёт узнать нужную строку.
response1 = requests.get(url)
page1 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response1.content, 'html.parser')
div_1 = page1.find("div", {"class": "file-name"})
item1 = div_1.get_text()
print(div_1)


Скачиват публичную страницу (буквально по той самой ссылке). Там есть meta теги

Получилось
Помогло сохраннение страницы не просто по ссылке, а через API яндекса
 def get_filename(link):
        ya_api = 'https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/public/resources/download?'
        url = ya_api + urlencode(dict(public_key=link))
        response = requests.get(url)
        page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        
        # Теперь нужно извлечь из страницы заветный filename
        # Не нашла, как парсить по meta-тегам, но помогло старое-доброе [start:end]
        
        page = str(page)
        start = page.find('filename=')  # обрезаем с нужного места
        end = page.rfind('disposition')  # обрезаем конец
        page = page[start:end]
        
        # Декодируем и убираем лишнее

        name = unquote(page)
        name = name.replace('filename=', '')
        name = name.replace('.jpg&amp;', '')
        name = name.replace('.ai&amp;', '')
        return name

